# How to find if the user is signing in for the first time in react firebase-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to find if the user is signed in for the first time or he has already signed in so that I can store the user data in firestore for further use. I am using [react-firebaseui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebaseui) in which the UI is automatically generated for the authentication. The data returned is not having the value if the user is signed in for the first time or not. Here is the code below

```
  const uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    signInMethod: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD,
    forceSameDevice: false,
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => false,
    },
  };


  useEffect(() => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        console.log("auth state changed");
        console.log(user);
      });    
  }, []);


// The UI part

<StyledFirebaseAuth
    uiConfig={uiConfig}
    firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
/>
```

Everything works perfectly fine but I am unable to get the data if the user is signed in for the first time or not. Help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When user first register, you can check `user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` in your sign in method where `user` is the sign in credentials

You can also check ( self explanatory )

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.creationTime === firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime
```

I believe it will also be available in your `user` object in `onAuthStateChanged`

```
user.metadata.creationTime === user.metadata.lastSignInTime
```

Comment: can you please tell me where exactly the `user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` is?  @SomeoneSpecial . It is not in the object returned in onAuthStateChanged.

Comment: I believe it should be retrieved from `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` in your ui options https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/#signinsuccesswithauthresultauthresult-redirecturl